# can I cancel a mkfs.vfat command

Tags: dual-boot, format

I'm running a dual-boot windows-ubuntu.
Yesterday, I ran the following command :

```
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda  
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1  
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/sda2
```

I thought it would help me to format my usb stick but when I tried to access my windows again, the partition was no longer bootable. And I couldn't access the windows data from ubuntu.

Does someone know a way to have access to my windows back or at least how to get my data ?

Sorry for any english mistake, it's not my native language

Comment: You formatted your HDD. There is no way to cancel it. You can try to save some data using testdisk. And you will have to reinstall OSes.

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/q/286181/167850

Answer (score -1):

For getting the data back try running a live ubuntu disk and select your drive with data and copy your data to your backup drive.

Comment: The data is not there any more. You can't just copy it from the formatted partitions.